# Rails with Bootstrap, jQuery, and jQuery-UI not working on Heroku

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an application on Rails 5 that uses Bootstrap, jQuery, and jquery_ui. I use jquery_ui for dropdown menus.

Dropdowns are broken on both development and production, I have no idea how to fix this.

[A screenshot of the errors/warnings in the web console (production)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aycRj.png) -- apparently I can't embed images, so I have to make do with a link.

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3', group: :development


#### HEROKU SPECIFIC GEMS #####
gem 'pg', '0.18.1', group: :production
################################

# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 5.0', '>= 5.0.5'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'

# Authentication with Devise
gem 'devise'

# Bootstrap framework
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.6'

# Markdown parser
gem 'redcarpet', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.4'

# Markdown syntax highlighting
gem 'coderay'

# Admin panel
gem 'remotipart', github: 'mshibuya/remotipart'
gem 'rails_admin', '>= 1.0.0.rc'

# Forms the easy way
gem 'simple_form', '~> 3.2', '>= 3.2.1'

gem 'seed_dump'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

ruby '2.3.1'
```

Application.js:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file. JavaScript code in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

Application.css.scss

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS/SCSS
 * files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 */
 @import 'jquery-ui/core.css';
 @import 'jquery-ui/datepicker.css';
 @import 'jquery-ui/theme.css';
 @import "bootstrap-sprockets";
 @import "bootstrap";

 .basic {
  td {
    padding: 5px;
  }
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.alert-alert {
  @extend .alert-warning;
}

.alert-notice {
  @extend .alert-info;
}

#accordion  {
  h3:focus {
    outline: none;
  }
  .ui-state-active {
    background-color: #00AAE3;
  }
}
```

...where am I going wrong? I've been researching this for the past three days and no dice.

### Edit:

Ran some tests. If I put Bootstrap above jQuery in Application.js, dropdowns work on development but not on production (like so):

```
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

However, I get reference errors ("can't find variable jQuery") on development (no errors on production).

If I require them in the order that I do in Application.js above my edit, I don't get any reference errors, but dropdowns are broken on both development and production.

Either way, I can't get them to work on production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the problem, making dropdowns work on both development and production. [The problem was that I was requiring Bootstrap twice.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKYKg.png) In fact, I was requiring everything twice. So I decided to look at my `application.html.erb`, and lo and behold, this is what I found:

```
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag :application %>
</head>
```

Nope, not good. Everything was being included twice. So I removed the first `javascript_include_tag`, and all my problems were solved!

Final `application.js`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

Final `application.css.scss`:

```
@import 'jquery-ui/core.css';
@import 'jquery-ui/datepicker.css';
@import 'jquery-ui/theme.css';
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

.basic {
 td {
    padding: 5px;
  }
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.alert-alert {
  @extend .alert-warning;
}

.alert-notice {
  @extend .alert-info;
}

#accordion  {
  h3:focus {
    outline: none;
  }
  .ui-state-active {
    background-color: #00AAE3;
  }
}
```

Final `application.html.erb` (the source of all my problems):

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag :application %>
</head>
```

Yep, stupid mistake and easily overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move `bootstrap-sprockets` after the jquery_ujs. Your file should look like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

In the documentation [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) it mentions this.

Also, looks like you have to require modules when using sass with jquery-ui-rails. Answer found in [this](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails/issues/89) thread. Change your application.css.scss to this:

```
 @import 'jquery-ui/core.css';
 @import 'jquery-ui/datepicker.css';
 @import 'jquery-ui/theme.css';
 @import "bootstrap-sprockets";
 @import "bootstrap";
```

Comment: Alright, no more errors on development...but now the dropdowns are broken on both development and production. And I'm still getting reference errors on production.

Comment: Odd. Did you restart the server? Precompile if necessary?

Comment: Yep. Ran `rake assets:clean`, `rake assets:precompile`, and restarted the server. Pushed to Heroku, and dropdowns are still broken, on both development and production...but I'm not getting any more reference errors in the web console.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your `application.scss` file as well?

Comment: Just did some quick research. Check out my edited answer

Comment: According to the screenshot you have an error in your css code. It's showing you have an unexpected ':'. Play around in the console and examine that specific line of code that it references to correct the error

Comment: Solved the problem. Thanks for your help!